# Existence and uniqueness for 2nd order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I believe I understand the general intuition behind the EUT for 1st order ode's, but why is continuity sufficient and  differentiability is not necessary for 2nd order linear odes, but is sufficient for first order ones? Is there intuition behind this?

I understand that the formattimg for the EUT for 1st and second order is different. Like the first order one talks about $ y'=F (t, y) $. Where as the second just looks at the coefficients of the ode.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to the existence and uniqueness theorem for second-order **linear** ODE's. In this case, the assumption that the equation is linear is what allows "nicer" conditions.

Comment: Oh ok, so with first order linear odes continuity is suffucient enough too for the EUT?

Comment: Yep. In that case $F(t,y) = f(t)y + g(t)$. What are the partial derivatives of that w.r.t. $y$?